# How to encrypt & encode a password with PowerShell v2?

Tags: powershell, encoding, base64, sha1

I'm trying to hit a web service using an SHA1 64 bit encoded password, but I'm not sure how to code this in powershell.

I tried using:
    PS C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI> $password = "password not shown here"

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI> $bytes =  System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($password)

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI> $encodedString = [Convert]::ToBase64CharArray($bytes)
```

But I got this back:

Cannot find an overload for "ToBase64CharArray" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:46
+ $encodedString = [Convert]::ToBase64CharArray <<<< ($bytes)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

I'm new with powershell, so this may not even be the right code to use.  I tried to modify an example I found online.

**Any ideas how to do this only in powershell using SHA1 encryption and base64 encoding?**

---

Okay, this works for the encoding, thanks to Jonathan for this part:

```
$str = "pwd"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($str)
$encodedStr = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

# and the result:
Write-Host $encodedStr
cAB3AGQA
```

I noticed the function call :: is sensitive to whitespace.  This works for the encryption piece.

```
$Sha1provider = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$hashBytes = $Sha1provider.ComputeHash($bytes)
Write-Host $hashBytes
114 168 243 129 97 21 246 249 22 4 38 215 241 185 174 86 116 201 7 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Convert.ToBase64CharArray` method doesn't have an overload with just one argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d0e5t57.aspx

You probably want to do:

```
$encodedString = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
write-host $encodedString
```

Note that base64 encoding is not SHA1 encoding. Look here: http://blog.logiclabz.com/c/function-to-encrypt-string-in-c-net-using-sha1-algorithm.aspx

Also, you don't necessarily have to convert C# code to Powershell.

You can use `Add-Type` to include C# code in your scripts.

PS: And I think you know that encoding is not encryption? http://www.blesta.com/2009/07/26/encoding-vs-encryption/